# android correct control of a service

Tags: android, service, lifecycle

I have a thread (Updater) inside a service (RefreshTasks) that check if there are some updates on the server. Then I have 4 activities that use those data. 
But I have a problem in managing this service... 
I would like to keep the service active along the whole application, even if the screen goes off. What is the correct practice to manage a service like this? In this moment I start and stop the service every onResume and onPause method of all activities... but this implies that the service will stop when the screen goes off.
Any suggestion?

Thanks AL.

Answer (score 0):

The Service instance continues to run also when your app is paused.
I suggest you to look also this service provided by Google, which is a good solution for push notification in communication between the device and your service:

https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/

And this is a good tutorial to start with:

http://blog.mediarain.com/2011/03/simple-google-android-c2dm-tutorial-push-notifications-for-android/

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't find answers to my questions with those links... You say that a service continue running in background until I stop it (or until it stops itself but it is not my case), that's correct but if I stat a service in the onResume of my activity, it will start again every time I return on that activity...

Comment: You can always save a boolean into your Service extended class which holds the actual state (running or not)